# Alguien me podría decir el error, la verdad no lo encuentro

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que imprima los números primos gemelos que se encuentran en cierto rango, me guíe con un video, pero el lenguaje que usaban en este es Matlab y yo lo intente pasar a c++ y por lo que veo cometí un error al hacerlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

El código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Andy Patricio Zavala Ortiz"<<endl;
    int b, ap,i, n1, n2, pch;
    bool esp=true;
    cout<<"Ingresa el primer numero(este debera ser el menor):\t";
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"Ingresa el segundo numero(este debera ser el mayor):\t";
    cin>>n2;
    i=1;
    pch=2;
    ap=0;
    for(i>=n1;i<=n2;i++)
    {
        while(esp=true and pch<i){
        if(i%pch==0){
            esp=false;
        }
        else
        {
            pch=pch+1;
        }
    }
    if(esp=true and ap==0){
        ap=i;
    }
    else if(esp=true and ap>=1)
    {
        b=i;
    }
    if(b-ap==2){
        cout<<ap<<" y "<<b<<" son numeros primos gemelos"<<endl;
    }
    ap=b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto una solución sencilla:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
bool esPrimo(int numero) {
  // Casos especiales
  if (numero == 0 || numero == 1 || numero == 4) return false;
  for (int x = 2; x < numero / 2; x++) {
    if (numero % x == 0) return false;
  }
  // Si no se pudo dividir por ninguno de los de arriba, sí es primo
  return true;
}
int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    cout<<"Ingresa el primer numero(este debera ser el menor):\t";
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"Ingresa el segundo numero(este debera ser el mayor):\t";
    cin>>n2;
    int a=0;
    while(n1<n2){
        a=n1+2;
        if(esPrimo( n1 ) == true && esPrimo( a ) == true){
            cout<<"Pareja de primos gemelos: "<<n1<< " y " <<a<<"\n";
        }
        n1++;
    }
}
```

y como resultado se obtiene esto:

```
Ingresa el primer numero(este debera ser el menor):     15
Ingresa el segundo numero(este debera ser el mayor):    30
Pareja de primos gemelos: 17 y 19
Pareja de primos gemelos: 29 y 31
```

Comment: Hijo mío, ahora mismo te veo como un salvador, llevo más de 3 horas en mucho sufrimiento, de verdad, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Todos los lugares donde añadiste "esp" (el while y los if's) están asignando a "esp" *true* y no están verificando que éste sea *true*.

Incluso puedes omitir el "esp == 1" (que sería la forma correcta) ya que el valor es booleano y no se necesitan operadores de comparación.

Por ejemplo:

```cpp
while (esp and pch<i)
// y
if (esp and ap==0)
```

Además en tus include usas librerías de C, para incluirlos en C++ se quita el .h del final y se agrega una c al principio.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: ya hice los cambios que me dijiste y solo me sale "2 y 0 son numeros primos gemelos"